# Keychain management command-line utility

Tags: terminal, bash, keychain, filevault, automation

I'am trying to fully automate the process **FileVault** setup on multiple OS X user machines.
E.g. to have a Bash script as a result.
One of the steps is `Institutional Recovery Key (IRK)` generation. This key is required to access encrypted hard disk without user credentials.
The generation command `sudo security create-filevaultmaster-keychain` create a public-private key pair.
But only the public one must be installed on the user machine.
I can delete it using `Keychain Access` utility.
But this is a GUI utility and cannot be called from the Bash.
So, how can i remove the private key from the keychain-file from the *command line*?

Or maybe there are already working scripts for this task :)

P.S. I've already read this but find no answer:
[IRK management](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/filevault-2-institutional-recovery-keys-creation-deployment-and-use/)
[security command man](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html)

Comment: You may have missed something in the [IRK management](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/filevault-2-institutional-recovery-keys-creation-deployment-and-use/) link. Have a look at: [fdesetup(8)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdesetup.8.html)

Comment: What exactly i've missed here? Sorry, i'm newbie in Mac and FileVault :(

Comment: Did you go back and reread the article and read the man page for fdesetup(8)?

Comment: Hmm, do you suggest ` fdesetup enable -certificate mycertfile.cer` option? and CER-file can be created using `sudo security create-filevaultmaster-keychain`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried recovering data with it yet but I think the following works:

```
security create-filevaultmaster-keychain ~/Desktop/FileVaultMaster.keychain

security export -k ~/Desktop/FileVaultMaster.keychain -t certs -o ~/Desktop/FileVaultMasterPublic.cer

sudo fdesetup changerecovery -institutional -certificate ~/Desktop/FileVaultMasterPublic.cer
```

In my case FileVault was already enabled so I just added it after the fact.

Comment: Nice solution - just export certificate for further using!
However, looks like there is no tool to remove private key...

Answer (score -1):

Type "man fdesetup" in the terminal app on your mac. Read the document.

Comment: Telling people to RTFM might be considered rude or at least not very helpful, especially for a Mac newbie. Can you at least indicate which part/option the OP should look at (or even cite it in your answer)?

Comment: @patrix Thanks for support! Looks like i should use `-certificate` option. However i must understand that a certificate Apple means first

Comment: I didn't use the term RTFM but I sincerely hope you were not offended@BughunterExtreme If you were, my humble apologies.